# Работа в RabbitMq (MassTransit) в консоли

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Есть такой код ресивера:

```
class Program
    {
        public static IBusControl BusControl;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                BusControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {
                    var host = cfg.Host("test.ru", 5672, "test", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("testtt");
                        h.Password("98989989");
                    });
                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "qTT", c => c.Consumer<MsgNewResultConsumer>());
                });
                BusControl.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                BusControl?.Stop();
                BusControl = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MsgNewResultConsumer : IConsumer<MsgNewResult>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MsgNewResult> context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Message.DiagnosticReportCode);
        }
    }
```

Код прекрасно работает в WinForms приложении, но если его скопировать в консольное или в службы виндовс, то не вызывается `Consume`. При этом нет никаких ошибок в оутпуте. В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Так может консолька заканчивает свое выполнение до того, как ваш код отработает? Попробуйте код запустить в отдельном потоке, а в консольке поставить `Console.ReadLine();` в конце, чтобы они сама не завершалась

Comment: и вот это `BusControl?.Stop();` наверное должно быть в finally блоке